# How to add inner shadow to image in CSS

Tags: html, css, image, display, box-shadow

I'm trying to add an inner shadow to an image, but I can't get the result that I want.

Here's what I have currently:

https://codepen.io/nvision/pen/lBKEy

```
.shadow {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 3px 3px 10px inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 3px 3px 10px inset;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 3px 3px 10px inset;
}

.shadow img {
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

The problem is this light-grey padding between the bottom of the image and the actual inner shadow. What I'd like to have is **no padding at all**. Just an inner shadow, and that's it.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: inner shadow css]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `display: block` to the `img` elements to remove the *padding* below. This is because `img` elements are rendered inline by default. All inline-block elements has some `vertical-align` value by default- reset it either by applying `vertical-align: top` or reset the `display` property by applying `display: block`. See demo below:

```css
/* apply a natural box layout model to all elements */
*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.shadow {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 3px 3px 10px inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 3px 3px 10px inset;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 3px 3px 10px inset;
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-in;
  transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-in;
}
.shadow:hover {
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 5px 5px 55px inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 5px 5px 55px inset;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 5px 5px 55px inset;
}
.shadow img {
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block; /* ADDED */
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <div class="shadow">
    <img src="http://fillmurray.com/250/250">
  </div>  
</div>

<div class="column">
  <div class="shadow">
    <img src="http://fillmurray.com/370/370">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="column">
  <div class="shadow">
    <img src="http://fillmurray.com/200/200">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="column">
  <div class="shadow">
    <img src="http://fillmurray.com/400/400">
  </div>
</div>
```